# How to Lock a user's account in MySQL 5.7?

Tags: database, privileges, mysql-5.7

There is a new security feature of user's account locking in MySQL 5.7.
Administrators can lock and unlock accounts for better control over who can log in.

I need the exact command to Lock / unlock the user's account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the MySQL Documentation, I got the answer, there is very simple command to LOCK and UNLOCK MySQL user:

```
ALTER USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' ACCOUNT LOCK;
ALTER USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

[Doc Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-locking.html)